# What is the name of this sci fi actor?

Tags: actors, actor-identification

I forget the name of an actor who was in some moderately succesful sci fi / fantasy films of late 1980s / early 1990s. I think his name is Michael D something which sounds French or Flemish. This actor is sort of a low-budget Jean Claude Van Damme and was in some movie with cyborgs that also was a series with several movies on the same theme if I'm not mistaken.

Who am I thinking of?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image: Michael Dudikoff]

I believe you may be referring to [Michael Dudikoff](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_Dudikoff) Star of the *American Ninja* series as well as several other low budget and made for TV movies.

Answer (score 2):

Could be Mark Dacascos - he played a 'prototype machine/human hybrid' in *Drive*.
[image]

Here's [his Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mark_Dacascos).

Comment: ALLEZ-CUISINE!!!

Comment: @ChrisB.Behrens ?

Comment: He's referring to Dacascos' role as The Chairman on Iron Chef.

Comment: @phantom42 Oh, right. I've never seen it, and he's not in it here...

Comment: @phantom42 That's not Iron Chef, that's a crappy imitation.  Real Iron Chefs and the Real Chairman can be seen here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Iron_Chef.JPG